# How can i make my grid view show multiple values (the number of values varies) in a single column cell?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i have to display data like this in grid view:

[image: Data to be displayed in grid view]

the problem is that:
for **each unique set** of manufacturer , model and type, the number of values associated with **watts column** changes ... that is, there is no fixed numbers of values in this single column. how can i display such a format in my grid view? Kindly help ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you just place another (nested) gridView in that column?  You'd have to use a template column in your parent grid, but then for each row, the number of records in that column could be different.

```
<asp:GridView ID="parentGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Manufacturer" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ModelNo" HeaderText="Model No" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Type" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Watts">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:GridView ID="nestedWattsView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" ShowHeader="false" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: u mean that for each column that has single unique values, i can use item template .. but specifically for "watts" column i will be placing another grid view in it?

Comment: can u give me example how to do this?

Comment: The gridview has bound column types, so for the single unique values you can use those or template columns.  But template columns for single values is overkill and wasted energy :).  The template column allows you to put more html or asp.net controls into it.

Comment: but i am un clear on how i will i fill that nested grid view ... are there any helping tutorial on such a case.. i am un able to resolve the issue